# How can i calculate sum of this linq to sql query?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm beginner in linq to sql, I using the c# linq to sql and wrote this query:

```
var query_find = (from t in behzad.Interconnect_Traffic_Analysis_Details
                  where t.FILEID == FILE_ID && t.code_operator.Trim() == item.code_operator.Trim()
                  select new { t.moddat }).ToList();
```

I want to calculate sum of the `t.moddat` column, how can I convert this query to sum the values? Thanks.

`t.moddat` is a `nvarchar(max)` datatype and save into that double datatype value.

Comment: If you want to **sum** it - why isn't it a **numeric** data type to begin with? You should **always** use the **most appropriate** datatype - not just define everything as `nvarchar(max)` ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 var query_find = (from t in behzad.Interconnect_Traffic_Analysis_Details
                                     where t.FILEID == FILE_ID && t.code_operator.Trim() == item.code_operator.Trim()
                                     select new
                                     {
                                        sum= t.moddat
                                     }).ToList();
 var sum= query_find.Sum(x => Convert.ToDouble(x.sum));
```

Comment: in  var sum=query_find.data.Sum(x => x.sum)-->data not know

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi check the answer. Updated

Comment: `Convert.ToDouble` should be inside `Sum`, not outside.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thank's but i get this error :Error 7 Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<AnonymousType#1,int>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type D:\New folder (2)\AMAZING REPORT\OSTAN\MASHAD\AR\AR\AR\Interconnect_Traffic_Analysis3.aspx.cs 83 64 AR

Comment: Remove the `.ToList()` if you want the query executed on the server. The code in this will tranfer all data to the client to perform the sum on the client machine.